# Почему условие цикла всегда True?

Tags: java

```
int[] setup = new int [10];
int setupField(){
    do {
         System.out.println  ("введите размер поля 5 или 10);
         Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
         String tmp = scn.nextLine();
         int size = Integer.parseInt (tmp);
         setup [2] = size;
     } while  (setup [2] != 5 || setup [2] != 10);
     return setup [2];
}
```

Хотел реализовать настройку размера поля но не могу понять почему не выполняется условие цикла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(setup [2] != 5 || setup [2] != 10)
```

одно из условий всегда будет истино

к примеру setup [2] = 5
первое условие setup [2] != 5 будет ложь, второе setup [2] != 10 истина итого истина

к примеру setup [2] = 10
первое условие setup [2] != 5 будет истина, второе setup [2] != 10 ложь итого истина

к примеру setup [2] = 15
первое условие setup [2] != 5 будет истина, второе setup [2] != 10 истина итого истина

Попробуйте

```
 (setup [2] != 5 && setup [2] != 10);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь все стало ясно!

Comment: Цикл заработал как надо с таким условием: while  (setup [2] != 5 && setup [2] != 10);

Comment: Да, верно. нужно было мое условие инвертировать

Comment: Я тут впервые, не разобрался пока что к чему)